# Can I smooth just 1 channel in a 3 channel image?

Tags: c++, python, c, opencv

Is there a OpenCV way to (gaussian) smooth just 1 channel in a 3 channel (RGB) image?

Any of Python or C or C++ OpenCV is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Split` to split the image into its channels and then use `Filter2D` on one of the components.

```
Split(src, src_r, src_g, src_b)
Smooth(src_r, dst_r)
Merge(dst_r, src_g, src_b, dst)
```